# Gets unknown error in class

Tags: php, web, pdo, error-handling

Im trying to make a token based system for my site, and im new in making classes in php. When i run a PDO query inside `check` function the page stop working.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Copenhagen");
include_once ("../connect.php");

class userToken {

    public $token;

    public $tokenid;
    public $userId;
    public $expire;

    function __construct($t) {
        $this->tokken = $t;
        $this->check();

    }

    public function check() {
        try {

            $checkToken = $DBH->prepare("
                SELECT *
                FROM token
                WHERE token = :token
                LIMIT 1
            ");

            $checkToken->execute(array(':token' => "186382asd"));

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo '[{"error":true"}]';
            exit();

        }
        return "done";

    }

}

$test = new userToken("186382asd");

echo $test->token;
?>
```

Comment: Please define: *page stop working*, did your cat exploded ?

Comment: BTW: 1) `tokken` !== `token` 2) `$DBH` is not defined anywhere. **<- PHP want to tell you all this**, but it can't because you don't have error reporting turned on

Comment: Would you take your car to the mechanic and say "My car has a problem, can you fix it?" without telling them what the problem is?

Comment: It dont give me an error the page just return error 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything in your code does not work;

- `$dbh` does not exist in your `check` method.
- Typo in your constructor `tokken`
- You are not setting `$this->token`
- Your injected token is not passed along to the method and therefore your query is not dynamic

I've reformatted the code;

```
// -- connect.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
// -- yourfile.php
$token = '186382asd';
$object = new UserToken($dbh);
var_dump($object->check($token)); // result or false

class UserToken {

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function check($token) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("
                SELECT *
                FROM token
                WHERE token = :token
                LIMIT 1
            ");
            return $stmt->execute(array(':token' => $token));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo '[{"error":true"}]';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have my DBH i make the `DBH` in another file

Comment: But `$dbh` can not be accessed in the class itself. You need to inject it, or initiate it in the class, but I recommend injecting it.

Comment: Yes i see. I worked then i ran the code. Thanks for the help.